# Rails - Carrierwave process throws ArgumentError: no images in this image list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

After attempting to implement a process to apply auto_orient! to my images I am getting this error:

```
ArgumentError (no images in this image list):
  app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:36:in `fix_exif_rotation'
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

Carrierwave works fine without the process but throws an error when I try to upload images after adding the process. Here's the process:

```
  process :fix_exif_rotation

  def fix_exif_rotation
    manipulate! do |image|
      image = image.auto_orient!
    end
  end
```

And here is my posts#create:

```
  def create
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @post = @user.posts.create(params[:post].permit(:text, :image))
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end
```

Comment: Can you also paste your params

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/UeJdkaHrOf3Uq6TW9Nqbqi+Or8fkW7bmTjGSOlFD6g=", "post"=>{"text"=>"", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f889cf51910 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140423-541-gyhkpl>, @original_filename="7.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[image]\"; filename=\"7.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Post"}

Comment: that weird do have a validation or show on carrierwave like whitelist and all

Comment: I don't think so. Here is my image_uploader.rb with the process commented out: https://github.com/ethanwilkins/social/blob/master/social/app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb and here is my Post model where the uploader is mounted: https://github.com/ethanwilkins/social/blob/master/social/app/models/post.rb

Comment: I eventually got a stack overflow instead but I got it working, no idea how, I just went back and tried using the process again and it worked

Comment: @ibanana's suggestion of installing ghostscript actually worked for me

Comment: remove the bang "!"  on the auto_orient!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got the same error, and fixed it by installing ghostscript

`brew install ghostscript`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, but had a different issue.  My code looked like:

```
def auto_orient(*args)  # remove `(*args)`
  manipulate! do |img|
    img = img.auto_orient
  end
end
```

Removing the `(*args)` fixed the issue.